# Stored procedure not matching TSQL code results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS off
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[TESTPARTSTATUS]
@PartNumber nvarchar(50)
as
begin
select * from VPPAPStatus where PartNumber = @PartNumber
end
```

The results I get with most part numbers work out just fine, but there are some part numbers that do not return any result. some are due to there is no data but some there is data and I can query in SSMS and I see the expected results. like below:

```
select * from VPPAPStatus where PartNumber = '84578452'
```

This returns 2 results (as expected) but when the same PartNumber is is run in the stored procedure there is no result??

---

Updates to question based on comments:

new test stored procedure is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS on
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER On
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[TESTPARTSTATUS]
@PartNumber nvarchar(50)
as
begin
select * from dbo.VPPAPStatus where PartNumber = @PartNumber
select * from dbo.VPPAPStatus where PartNumber = '84578452'
select @partnumber as 'INPUTPN' 

end
```

when This runs, I get no results when selecting by @PartNumber, 2 results when selecting by '84578452' and the text '84578452' returned back as the InputPN

I am totally confused by this behavior any ideas where or what to check??

Comment: How are you executing the sp?

Comment: Check the actual execution plan for each, is the Partnumber column also nvarchar(50)? And are part numbers numeric only or do they actually include foreign unicode characters?

Comment: Try the same SELECT statement in SSMS, but put "N" in front of the string to make it unicode: N'84578452'. See if you get the same result.

Comment: select * from VPPAPStatus where PartNumber = N'84578452' provides the same result, 2 records

Comment: Partnumber column is also nvarchar(50) most part numbers are 8 digits but there are many that are alphanumeric 5-6 characters

Comment: Side note: `SET ANSI_NULLS off` and `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` is a bad idea

Comment: do you use schemas other than `dbo`? Add `dbo.` prefix to tablename to be sure.

Comment: @stu adding 'dbo.' did not change behavior

Comment: @charlieface - I read in a different thread they might be messing with the queries so I was playing with them, both are set to ON normally

Comment: Can you try creating a copy of the proc for testing and include the same `select` with the string literal also and compare execution plan, also print the `@PartNumber` value.

Comment: Show us the code that you use to *invoke* your stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frustrated and looking for a work around I used `like LTrim(RTrim(@PartNumber))`
Annoyingly, this worked right away.

Since I select from a View, I modified the view to trim the PN selection up front this solved the issue for any other SP's that use the same fields

Even though when I copied and pasted the values side by side in notepad and didn't see any special characters or spaces, there must have been something tripping up the stored procedure.

Lesson Learned - Make Sure data is trimmed before going into the database.